# Save markups through forge apis

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to save a markup through the forge api from an external application, using the viewer api and later access the BIM360 platform to be able to view it in the list of markups?

- Custom Application

[image localhost custom app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLYx2.jpg)

- Web BIM360

[Web BIM360 Autodesk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsc7h.jpg)

autodesk-viewer

autodesk-bim360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, BIM360 Markups API is not available yet. So, you need to save markup data you got from [MarkupExt#generateData()](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v4/reference/javascript/markupscore/#generatedata) to your backend & database yourself. But please stay tuned with us. Once BIM360 Markups API is released, we will post an announcement for that. We apologize for any inconvenience had caused to you.